# Putty and XMing: Save X11 Forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, putty

Normally to enable X11 Forwarding when using Putty, you have to check "Enable X11 forwarding" under the SSH tab. Is there a way to save this that I don't have to check the box every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session settings in Putty can be saved by providing a name in the Saved Sessions box and clicking Save on the session Tab.